# How to retrieve data from database to textbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Need help on my codes. I need to show my data(Firstname and Lastname) from my database to a textbox but i can't figure out the code. Need help. Thnx. Here's the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

and the code: error at line 5

```
Private Sub dg1_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg1.RowEnter
    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "SELECT ID, LastName, FirstName FROM tblMembers WHERE ID = @ID"
        .Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = dg1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
    End With
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    With dr
        .Read()
        txtLname.Text = .GetValue("LastName")
        txtFname.Text = .GetValue("FirstName")
    End With
    Try
        txtContactNo.Text = dg1.Item(2, e.RowIndex).Value
        txtAddress.Text = dg1.Item(3, e.RowIndex).Value
        dtpBirthday.Text = dg1.Item(4, e.RowIndex).Value
        dtpBaptism.Text = dg1.Item(5, e.RowIndex).Value
        txtMinistry.Text = dg1.Item(6, e.RowIndex).Value
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(changePhoto(CInt(dg1.SelectedCells(0).Value)))
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Not much in the way of details here but I suspect that if you try to debug this you will find there are no SelectedRows.

Comment: @SeanLange I think so too. Do you have a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use `DataGridViewCellEventArgs.RowIndex` instead of `dg1.SelectedRows(0)`

> This event occurs before the CurrentRow property is updated. To retrieve the index of the newly-entered row, use the DataGridViewCellEventArgs.RowIndex property within the event handler.
>   from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

```
.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = dg1(0, e.RowIndex).Value
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. But now I have a problem with the connection. It says that .executereader needs an open connection, but when I do open the connection, it says that the connection was not closed when I add cn.Open().

Comment: Could you check you have close every connection after used? And also check the `cn.state` in debug mode, to check what happening of your connection.

Comment: it's working, just made a few tweaks. but thanks for the help. :)